# domain-specific robots file with htaccess rewrite robots.txt to example.com.txt or fallback to default.txt

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to have domain-specific robots.txt and so far this works:

```
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots/%{HTTP_HOST}.txt [L]
```

But I would like to have a fallback so if the domain.txt file doesn't exist then go to default.txt

And this doesn't really work out as it will redirect all non-existent filenames, plus I already have a !-f in a different rule:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule robots/default.txt [L]

So I would need to:
1-catch robots.txt requests
2-Send to robots/domain.txt if it exists
3-Else send to robots/default.txt

Comment: _“plus I already have a !-f in a different rule”_ – so what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/robots/%{HTTP_HOST}.txt -f
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots/%{HTTP_HOST}.txt [L]

RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots/domain.txt [L]
```

The condition in the first rule checks that the destination robots file exists, and if it does, `robots.txt` gets rewritten. Thus, the second rule only gets applied if the first rule doesn't.